# Determine host type ( selfhost vs iis ) for a wcf service exposing basichttp binding

Tags: wcf, hosting, configurationmanager, basichttpbinding

There is a service  , exposing one endpoint as basic http binding. 
I have two types of hosting ( selfhost for test ,iis for production)

I am using configurationmanager which has to read a service model section from config. 
Of course , when it is self host a config file is myapp.exe.config located in the same path as executing assembly and when it is running under iss , it is web.config .

So i want to use configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration and provide it a path to config.

But i need to understand what hosting type is used now.  There is no httpcontex.current because it is basic http binding. ( if it was , i would be able to use it in order to check if its is null and if not, it is iss hosting ).

How to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused: ConfigurationManager should know to read appSettings from bith appp and web config.

You also probably need not to read Service Model section by your self - let wcf do it for you. It also can care about config.

You can also setup service details in code - to avoid config search.

If you have no choice (i'd use as last option) - may be try to use Assembly's running exe path, like 
`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`

Comment: I need to read service model section for my application logic.Unfortunately configuration manager will not be able to read a proper file under iss hosting.Assembly.getexecutingassmbly will not work also under iss.

Comment: Ok, but it will for win.service, right? So you can use it as difference.

Comment: No it is not windows service. It is eather hosted in iis or wpf. Under iis getexecutingassembly will not work.